# Cannot Get/ when express app is deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

my dir structure

```
/src
   --/public
   --/server.ts
--package.json
--package-lock.json
```

above is my director structure

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));
// app.use(express.static("/public/"));


const path = require("path");


app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, + "public", 'index.html'));
    res.sendFile(__dirname , "index.html");

    //res.send('Testing one two');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || '5005';
app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server running on port 5005"));
```

when I run the above code, it works well on my local machine but won't work when it is deployed to Heroku,
I tried just passing a string like this and it worked, but when I want to render a static file like the HTML file it wont work on heroku, any help? i think the problem is my directory structure

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
      
        res.send('Testing one two');
    });
```

Comment: `res.sendFile` expects path to the file in the first argument. This `res.sendFile(__dirname , "index.html");` is equivalent to this `res.sendFile(__dirname);` The second argument is options object. Read the docs http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, `express.static` middleware is separate from `res.sendFile`. In other words, even if you set `express.static` to `public`, it will not do anything to `res.sendFile`, as it takes the first parameter as a path.

In my humble opinion, it would be better if you were to use an absolute path, like the following snippet below.

```js
const path = require('path');

/** Code here... **/

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

Explanations:

- `path.join` is an utility to join path segments into one path. It is cross-platform compatible.
- `__dirname` will get the current directory that the script is running from.

Further reading: [Express methods](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

Comment: It worked on the local host but am getting not found on heroku

Comment: Have you also deployed the `index.html` file? Did you store it inside the `public` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the address of the index.html file in the path for the code mentioned below and paste this code at the end of the inside of the express file and everything will work perfectly fine and you are good to go.

```
 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'));
      });
```